# ODBC Connection string for php

Tags: php, mysql, html, odbc

I had developed one website purely in **HTML**.I have my form with fields like name,address,qualification etc.On click of **submit** button, i wanted to save these details into **mysql** database.

I installed  mysql driver(mysqlconnector) using **myodbc-3.51.11-2-win.msi** setup.The **ODBC** connection from control panel is also done successfully.

From my html page i am calling php page as follow:

```
<form action="database.php" method="post">
```

I am coding in **CSE html validator**.
I wanted the code to connect to **mysql** database using **odbc** connection from **php**.

I installed XAMPP on my system.Does **CSE html validator** support php??
Please help me out.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your MySQL DB will be stored in client, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possibility of implementing this aside, this strikes me as a terrible idea - you're going to include the connection string in plaintext on the client side, so that anyone accessing the HTML page can see your DB username & password?

You could technically do this using ActiveX - Google 'ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");' for information on that, but it would only really work on Internet Explorer browsers. You'd be much better off implementing a server-side interface in a language such as PHP, C#, or even Server-Side JS (ie Node.js) to maintain security & cross-browser compatibility.